# (SliverAppBar) what is that white space?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

##I want to have a Floating appBar with search Textfield. But when i scroll the page then created a padding or gape something (picture 2). Why this is showing and how to remove it? ##

[[image: Before Scroll]] [1][image: That is after scroll screen]

> That's before scroll screen     > After scrolls the screen, why there is white space or padding?
> How to remove that space?

```
class _SalesScreenState extends State<SalesScreen> {
  String searchText = "";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200,
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            title: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 35,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/icons/search.svg",
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline6,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      //    prefixIcon: Svg.assets(),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                      hintText: '검색',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
                    hintText: 'Tell us about yourself',
                    helperText: 'Keep it short, this is just a demo.',
                    labelText: 'Life story',
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    prefixText: ' ',
                    suffixText: 'USD',
                    suffixStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: 600,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Help! thanks :D I want to add a Textield in a floating Appbar was the main goal.
After scrolls the screen, why there is white space or padding?
How to remove that space?

---

Answer (score -1):

Oh. FlexibleSpaceBar have a titlePadding. That's have a default padding around title.

> Solution:

```
 flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              title: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
```